# Is there a way to return firebase records from a filter as you type matching letters

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a search screen that searches the firebase users collection for matching displayNames.  But I'd like to return a list based on the first letters as they're typed.

For example, you have John, Johnny, Jack.

When typing J all three appear.  When you type 'Jo' then only the first two appear.

Here is my code that works but only works when you type the entire DisplayName

```js
  search(event) {
    console.log('event', event.target.value);
    let searchKey: string = event.target.value;
    console.log('searchKey', searchKey);
    let firstLetter = searchKey;
    console.log('firstLetter', firstLetter);

    if (searchKey.length === 0) {
      this.sampleArr = [];
      this.resultArr = [];
    }

    if (this.sampleArr.length === 0) {
      this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('displayName', '==', firstLetter))
        .snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
          data.forEach(childData => {
            this.sampleArr.push(childData.payload.doc.data());
          });
        });
    }
  }
```

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="search($event)"></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-item *ngFor="let user of sampleArr" (click)="sendUserRequest(user)">
    <ion-avatar style="padding-right: 10px;">
      <img [src]="user.profilePic" alt="" srcset="">
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>
      <ion-note style="font-weight:bold; color: black;">
        Send request to
      </ion-note>  
      <ion-note style="font-weight:bold; color: black;">
        {{user?.displayName}}
      </ion-note>  
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using the `>` and `<=` operators:

```
ref.where('displayName', '>=', 'J')
   .where('displayName', '<', 'K')
```

This query gives you everything starting with a `J`.

A common way to write this query is:

```
ref.where('displayName', '>=', 'J')
   .where('displayName', '<=', 'J\uF7FF')
```

The `\uF7FF` in this second query is just the last known Unicode character, so anything starting with a J is guaranteed to be before that. This way of coding it is easier, because you don't need to determine the next letter.

Comment: This works for the first letter but say you have a user 'Ma' and a user 'Me'.  Is there a way to make 'Me' go away once you type in 'M' 'a'?

Comment: The `J` in the code can be any string you're searching for. So to get any documents where the display name starts with `Ma`, you'd do: `ref.where('displayName', '>=', 'Ma').where('displayName', '<=', 'Ma\uF7FF'`

Comment: the problem is that it's not removing users with 'Me' in their names when I type 'Ma'.

For example, when I type 'M' I get the following list

'Ma'
'Me'

But when I type 'a' then it's not removing the user 'Me'.

Comment: You'll need to clear `this.sampleArr` each time you perform a new search query.

Comment: Thanks actually what I thought but it's not working.  Would you mind updating the code to show where that would go, please?  If you notice in my above post I'm clearing it but it actually never really get's cleared with this.sampleArr = [].

Comment: Actually, I found where it should go.  I added it at the top of the search event and it works.  I appreciate your help Frank